# Web cam in Adobe Flash saving

Tags: flash, actionscript, webcam

I have made a photobooth app on flash, it take images fine and you are able to save the image but i want it to save to a file automatically when the save button is pressed without a file directory opening?

Comment: Where do you want to save it?

Answer (score 0):

With Flash Player, your best option is to save the data to a local [`SharedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) (or several).  To save explicitly to the filesystem, the player will require a file dialog.

Since you're saving images, you may want to change the default configuration of required disk space, to minimize user prompting.

Using AIR, you'd have access to `File` and `FileStream`, which would allow saving data to arbitrary locations without prompting.